# Can't get VLC to write new file (trimming, not transcoding)

Tags: command-line, video, vlc-media-player, video-editing

I’m trying to create a new file using VLC that is trimmed from the original. I do not wish to transcode. I'm using the command:

```
vlc -I dummy "L:\temp\input.mp4" --start-time 71 --stop-time 74 --sout-standard-access=file --sout-standard-dst="L:\test2.mp4"
```

I get no error messages pertaining to `L:` drive access, the file plays (in subset), but no new file is created. What am I missing? When using `-vvv`, I get no errors requiring further parameters, making me think I’m not missing a required param, but I can’t tell.

Note: I know I can use `:sout` to chain the parameters more elegantly, but for the sake of debugging and learning (the [CLI documentation](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html) isn't new-user-friendly), I’m endeavoring to list each parameter as described on that page:

```
You may also use the following syntax :  
`% vlc input_stream --sout-module1-option1=... --sout-module1-option2=... --sout-module2-option1=... --sout-module2-option2=... ...`
```

Edit for clarity:

VLC is in my PATH.

Breaking down the command, I understand it to mean:

- `vlc` Run VLC
- `-I dummy` Display a dummy (CLI feedback) interface
- `"L:\temp\input.mp4"` Input file is this
- `--start-time 71` Start at 71 seconds
- `--stop-time 74` Stop at 74 seconds
- `--sout-standard-access=file` Output using `Standard` accessing a 'file'
- `--sout-standard-dst="L:\test2.mp4"` Output using `Standard` destination is `L:\test2.mp4`